# How to add additional input parameter in Layout Service?

Tags: layout-service

We are trying to use Sitecore Layout service to get Sitecore content in JSON format. Is it possible to add additional parameter which we can read and use to customize the Layout service output?

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: Yes it is possible. Try this - https://blogs.perficient.com/2024/02/09/extending-layout-service-in-sitecore-headless/

Answer (score 0):

You can customize your `Layout Service` by extending the class `JssGetLayoutServiceContextProcessor` provided by Headless Services.

You can override the following method:

```
protected override void DoProcess(GetLayoutServiceContextArgs args, AppConfiguration application)
```

Inside this method, you can use below code to ready the query string:

```
string queryStringValue = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Query["query_string"];
```

You can use `queryStringValue` in your business need.

Hoping it will help you.

https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/hd/190/sitecore-headless-development/extend-the-getlayoutservicecontext-pipeline.html

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I will check and update the answer